# ayuda Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php 

class Insertar{
    public $mensaje;
    public $nombre;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $genero;

    public function insert()
    {
        $model = new Conexion();
        $conexion = $model->conectar();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 'usuarios'('nombre', 'email', 'password', 'genero') VALUES(:nombre, :email, :password, genero)";
        $consulta = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $consulta->bindParam(':nombre', $this->nombre);
        $consulta->bindParam(':email', $this->email);
        $consulta->bindParam(':password', $this->password);
        $consulta->bindParam(':genero', $this->genero);

        if (!$consulta)
        {
            $this->mensaje = $conexion->errorInfo();
        }
        else
        {
            $consulta->execute();
            $this->mensaje = "genial, has registrado un usuario";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: lee [ask], pasa el [tour] y mejora tu pregunta :)

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis te falta dos puntos en `genero` al formar tu consulta debe ser asi : `:genero`

Comment: muchas gracias...